# How to access live webcam feed on google colab?

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, webcam, opencv

I am working on a project in which I need to access video feed from my local webcam.
Is there any way to access my local webcam while working on google colab?

I have tried following code but doesn't work on colab

```
import cv2

vid_feed = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    check, frame = vid_feed.read()
    cv2.imshow('feed', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 'q':
        break

vid_feed.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

(First one Sorry for my english) you need to go to the left panel and click in the "<>" option

[image]

Once this is done, in the right panel, you can see the option "Camera capture", if you click on this button a script will open that you must execute to be able to use the webcam.

[image]